# StageText issues with autocorrect and restrict

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, autocorrect

I am attempting to use StageText in an Android AIR app as follows:

```
var tf:StageText = new StageText();
tf.stage = stage;
tf.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth, 90); 
tf.text = "Test";
tf.editable = true;
tf.autoCorrect = false;
tf.fontSize = 50;
tf.color = 0xFF0000;
tf.maxChars = 12;
tf.restrict = "A-Za-z";
```

When editing this StageText on an Android device everything works as expected until you hit the delete button. Until now, no autocorrect suggestions will have been displayed, but once the delete button is pressed autocorrect suggestions will now start to be displayed. Now, the next key you press will insert the autocorrected word at the cursor position instead of whatever key you pressed (e.g. if you press "s" it will insert "Son" if that was the autocorrect suggestion).

The really weird thing is that this behaviour only occurs if I set the restrict property on the StageText - if I comment out the restrict line everything functions exactly as I would expect.

Comment: Do any of the autocorrected words have values not in "A-Za-z"?

Comment: @Gone3d Nope - they all match the restrict "A-Za-z".

Comment: Just tested your code and can confirm that this is indeed happening on both my Nexus 7 tablet and Galaxy Nexus phone running Android 4.2.1.  Very strange.  You may have stumbled across a legitimate bug, especially since Android's keyboard included a significant update with Android 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs ([flash.text.StageText.restrict](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StageText.html#restrict)):

> Note: Restrictions apply only to user input; a script can insert any
>   characters into the text field.

Since restrictions are not 100% reliable, instead of assigning value to the textfield's `restrict` property, you could evaluate the text yourself using your own logic ([RegExp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/RegExp.html)) in a `CHANGE` event handler.  This would give you full control over what users enter into the textfield.

```
tf.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, textFieldChangeEventHandler);

private function textFieldChangeEventHandler(event:Event):void
{
    trace(event.target.text);
    //Manage text
}
```

Comment: This is a great workaround to an annoying bug. One thing to note: in the change handler I had to manually reset the cursor position to where it should be after removing any unallowed characters as by default the cursor would reposition itself to the beginning of the text.